# How does one pronounce "Mekillot"?

Tags: dark-sun, pronunciation

In the Dark Sun campaign setting, there are creatures called "Mekillot" - and I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to pronounce their names!  Is it hard, like "Me-Kill-Lot", or soft like "Me-Kill-Oh"?  Or something else entirely?

I have not seen a pronunciation guide in this version of Dark Sun, and I do not have any of the older versions.  What is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: This means if you don't have some source for its pronunciation, please don't answer with "what you say."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no pronunciation guide in the original first release 2e materials I have. I presume you are referencing 4e when you say "this version". So I don't think there's a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: "there's no pronunciation guide" seems a correct answer, idk why this would be downvoted -- unless someone has a pronounciation guide theyre not using to answer?